# Rule to validate dynamic array

Tags: php, laravel

I have a details.blade.php that has a form for the user select how many tickets want for each ticket type:

```
<ul>
    @foreach($tickets as $ticket)
        <li>
            <span>{{$ticket->title}}</span> 
            <form method="post" action="{{route('congress.registration', ['id' => $congress->id, 'slug' => $congress->slug])}}">

                <select name=types[{{ $ticket->title }}]>
                    <option selected>0</option>
                    ...
                </select>
            </form>
            <span>X {{$ticket->showPrice()}}</span>
        </li>
    @endforeach
    <li>
        <span>TOTAL</span>
        <span>0.00€</span>
    </li>
    <input type="submit" value="Next"/>
    </form>
```

When user click in "Next" the storeQuantity() method in the RegistrationController receives the data and stores in an array.

My doubt is how to validate in the RegistrationController the quantity introduced by the user before store this in the array?

**The rule context is:** Each ticket type has a column minPerUser and a maxPerUser column in database. For example, the TicketType table has a  ticket type with name "full access" with the minPerUser value as "1" and the maxPerUser value as "4". So in the select menu the user can only select values between 1 and 4 for the ticket type "full access".

So if a user introduce for example in the source code the quantity as "100" for the ticket type "full access" the validate should result in an error.

Do you know how to have a validation rule for this context?

**RegistrationController**

```
class RegistrationController extends Controller

   public function storeQuantity(Request $request){
        
        //dd($request->all());

         $this->validate($request, [
             // how to validate here the quantities by the user?
        ]);

        $typeQuantities = $request->get('types');

        $total = 0;
        foreach($typeQuantities as $typeName => $quantity){
            $type = TicketType::where('name', $typeName)->firstOrFail();
            $price = $type->price;

            $selectedTypes[$type->name]['quantity'] = $quantity;
            $selectedTypes[$type->name]['price'] = $price;
            $selectedTypes[$type->name]['subtotal'] = $price * $quantity;
           
        }
        return view('congresses.registration')->with('selectedTypes', $selectedTypes);
    }
  }
```

The "dd($request->all());" shows:

```
   array:2 [▼
      "_token" => ""
      "types" => array:2 [▼
        "ticket type 1" => "2"
        "ticket type 2" => "1"
      ]
    ]
```

**TicketType Model:**

```
class TicketType extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'price', 'minperUser', 'maxPerUser','congress_id'
    ];
    public function congress(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Congress');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class RegistrationController extends Controller{

public function createTypeValidationRules($types){
    $rules = array();
    foreach( $types as $typeName ){
        $type = TicketType::where('name', $typeName)->firstOrFail();
        $rules[$type->name] = 'between:'.$type->min.','.$type->max
    }
    return $rules;
}


public function storeQuantity(Request $request){
    $typeQuantities = $request->get('types');
    $rules = $this->createTypeValidationRules(typeQuantities);
    $validator = Validator::make($typeQuantities,$rules);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        //do whatever you want in case of error here..
        return false;
    }
    $total = 0;
    foreach($typeQuantities as $typeName => $quantity){
    $type = TicketType::where('name', $typeName)->firstOrFail();
    $price = $type->price;

    $selectedTypes[$type->name]['quantity'] = $quantity;
    $selectedTypes[$type->name]['price'] = $price;
    $selectedTypes[$type->name]['subtotal'] = $price * $quantity;

    }
    return view('congresses.registration')->with('selectedTypes', $selectedTypes);
}
```

}

This is not tested something like this will help..

Comment: If you can explain your code, what it does, or why you've done it that way, it'll make it much more useful for the OP.

Comment: Thanks, but in the first foreach "    foreach( $typeQuantities as $typeName ){"  this "$typeQuantities" variable is not defined.

Comment: updated the answer so that it will solve the undefined issue. i made  a mistake by adding the wrong variable name, $typeQuantities instead of $types